OpenAI API error: "Configuration is not a constructor"
I'm trying to build a Discord bot that generates images, but I faced a problem. I'm getting the following error:

Configuration is not a constructor

I'm following a YouTube tutorial. I have the following code:
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require(`discord.js`);
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'My Key'
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Problem
The code you have works with the OpenAI Node.js SDK <v4, but you're using >=v4.
Solution
The following is the correct initialization if you're using the OpenAI Node.js SDK >=v4:
import OpenAI from "openai";

const client = new OpenAI(
  {apiKey: "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
);

Then you can use, for example, the Images API as follows:
 import OpenAI from "openai";

 const client = new OpenAI(
  { apiKey: "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
 );

async function main() {
  const image = await client.images.generate({ model: "dall-e-3", prompt: "A cute baby sea otter" });

  console.log(image.data);
}

main();


How is it used it on the image generator?
